# Weird NSString behavior with formatString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I ran into a pretty weird issue today.
I have this static method (part of a CommonUtilities source file that I've been just created that gathers all the small common methods I'd like to access anywhere in my code, like I usually do btw...)

I just want to convert a number into its scientific value using the international system notation (k, M, G, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
+ (NSString*)scientificFormatedStringForValue:(NSNumber*)value andUnits:(NSString*)_units
{
    NSMutableString* retStr = [NSMutableString string];
    long long longValue = [value longLongValue];
    if (longValue > 1000000000)
    {
        [retStr appendFormat:@"%d Md%@", longValue / 1000000000, _units];
    }
    else if (longValue > 1000000)
    {
        [retStr appendFormat:@"%d M%@", longValue / 1000000, _units];
    }
    else if (longValue > 1000)
    {
        [retStr appendFormat:@"%d k%@", longValue / 1000, _units];
    }
    else
    {
        [retStr appendFormat:@"%d %@", longValue, _units];
    }
    return retStr;
}
```

This is pretty easy right?
Ok, here's the deal: the `_units` is not converted properly.

In my example, I use this:

```
[CommonUtilities scientificFormatedStringForValue:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:longValue] andUnits:@"€"];
```

I get `(null)` as `_units` for the formatted string. If I print the value of `_units`, it's a dot. So, to try to debug this, I just replaced:

```
[retStr appendFormat:@"%d M%@", longValue / 1000000, _units];
```

with

```
[retStr appendFormat:@"%d M%@", longValue / 1000000, @"€"];
```

Still doesn't work. It tried passing a single character (thinking the maybe the € must be converted to some UTF8 stuff or whatever. So I changed the calling method to :

```
[CommonUtilities scientificFormatedStringForValue:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:longValue] andUnits:@"e"];
```

Still crappy stuff. I even changed @"€" to [NSString stringWithString:@"€"], but still the same output! I can't figure out what's wrong here, I'm stuck.

I thought of a problem in the encoding of the source file, so I deleted it and recreated it, but still the same issue....

If any one has even the tiniest clue, that would be most helpful. Thank you guys...

Comment: You've got [retStr appendFormat:@"%d Md%@", longValue / 1000000000, _units], don't you mean appendFormat:@"%d Gd%@"? Giga not mega?

Comment: Have you tried creating the `NSString` inside the method, just to be sure?

Comment: @Gnat That looks like French for billion (Milliard).

Comment: @jv42: Ah - that would explain it. That's localisation!

Comment: @Radada: if you're not doing anything else in your method, you don't really need a `NSMutableString`, you could directly create and return your string.

Comment: Try the escaped unicode euro symbol, raw unicode in source code can have unusual effects: `andUnits:@"\u20AC"`. What does the output look like when you put in @"e"?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with a plain @"e"

Comment: @Radada, what version of Mac OS X, XCode and compiler are you using?

Comment: actually, the problem came from using %d instead of %lld. I don't know why it confused NSString and messed the second part of the formatString, but still, it worked :-/
Thx all for your comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to write an `int` (32 bits) but you are passing a `long long` (64 bits) and it is reading the first 4 bytes of your `longValue` for the `value` and the last 4 bytes for the `_units`. It just so happens that the value in low bytes of your `long long` is `nil` and did not cause a crash. You need to use `%lld` instead of `%d` to print the long value correctly.

```
    longValue       NSString*
/---------------\ /---------\
|   8 bytes     | | 4 bytes |
\---------------/ \---------/
^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
   %d       %@        This gets ignored.
(reads 4) (reads this 4 bytes which happen to be nil)
```

Comment: Waoh, thx for this complete answer :)) I understand it a little bit more now. Thx Joe ^^